# Need to Initialization js while ajax response magento 2

Tags: magento2, ajax, jquery

Need to Initialization js for particular div when the div append ajax response magento 2.

i have append the div in ajax response and also i need initialize js for that div.

How to do that

Comment: How do you mean "initialize js"? can't you just define a function on pageload and then execute it after you have appended the div? else share some code pls

Comment: After appended the div, i need to initialize custom js for this div

Comment: Yes, but how does your code look so far, and which error do you get / what is happening / what do you expect to happen?